# Stable merging two arrays to maximize product of adjacent elements

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, dynamic-programming

The following is an interview question which I am unable to answer in a complexity less than an exponential complexity. Though it seems to be an DP problem, I am unable to form the base cases and analyze it properly. Any help is appreciated.

> You are given 2 arrays of size 'n' each. You need to stable-merge
>   these arrays such that in the new array sum of product of consecutive
>   elements is maximized.

**For example**

> A= { 2, 1, 5}
>
> B= { 3, 7, 9}

Stable merging A = {a1, a2, a3} and B = {b1, b2, b3} will create an array C with 2*n elements.  For example, say C = { b1, a1, a2, a3, b2, b3 } by merging (stable) A and B. Then the sum = b1*a1 + a2*a3 + b2*b3 should be a maximum.

Comment: This link may be helpful, http://www.ocf.berkeley.edu/~wwu/cgi-bin/yabb/YaBB.cgi?board=riddles_cs;action=display;num=1280183627

Comment: He has already mentioned we have to do stable merging. Stable means that the order for the numbers must be retained. Means 2 in the first array should always come before 1 in the first array. 

Just have a look at what stability is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets define c[i,j] as solution of same problem but array start from i to end for left. And j to end for right.
So c[0,0] will give solution to original problem.

c[i,j] consists of.

1. MaxValue = the max value.
2. NeedsPairing = true or false = depending on left most element is unpaired.
3. Child = [p,q] or NULL = defining child key which ends up optimal sum till this level.

Now defining the optimal substructure for this DP

```cs
c[i,j] = if(NeedsPairing) { left[i]*right[j] } + Max { c[i+1, j], c[i, j+1] }
```

It's captured more in detail in this code.

```cs
if (lstart == lend)
{
    if (rstart == rend)
    {
        nodeResult = new NodeData() { Max = 0, Child = null, NeedsPairing = false };
    }
    else
    {
        nodeResult = new NodeData()
        {
            Max = ComputeMax(right, rstart),
            NeedsPairing = (rend - rstart) % 2 != 0,
            Child = null
        };
    }
}
else
{
    if (rstart == rend)
    {
        nodeResult = new NodeData()
        {
            Max = ComputeMax(left, lstart),
            NeedsPairing = (lend - lstart) % 2 != 0,
            Child = null
        };
    }
    else
    {
        var downLef = Solve(left, lstart + 1, right, rstart);

        var lefResNode = new NodeData()
        {
            Child = Tuple.Create(lstart + 1, rstart),
        };

        if (downLef.NeedsPairing)
        {
            lefResNode.Max = downLef.Max + left[lstart] * right[rstart];
            lefResNode.NeedsPairing = false;
        }
        else
        {
            lefResNode.Max = downLef.Max;
            lefResNode.NeedsPairing = true;
        }

        var downRt = Solve(left, lstart, right, rstart + 1);

        var rtResNode = new NodeData()
        {
            Child = Tuple.Create(lstart, rstart + 1),
        };

        if (downRt.NeedsPairing)
        {
            rtResNode.Max = downRt.Max + right[rstart] * left[lstart];
            rtResNode.NeedsPairing = false;
        }
        else
        {
            rtResNode.Max = downRt.Max;
            rtResNode.NeedsPairing = true;
        }

        if (lefResNode.Max > rtResNode.Max)
        {
            nodeResult = lefResNode;
        }
        else
        {
            nodeResult = rtResNode;
        }
    }
}
```

And we use memoization to prevent solving sub problem again.

```cs
Dictionary<Tuple<int, int>, NodeData> memoization = new Dictionary<Tuple<int, int>, NodeData>();
```

And in end we use NodeData.Child to trace back the path.

Answer (score 1):

For A = {a1,a2,...,an}, B = {b1,b2,...,bn},

Define DP[i,j] as the maximum stable-merging sum between  {ai,...,an} and {bj,...,bn}.

(1 <= i <= n+1, 1 <= j <= n+1)

DP[n+1,n+1] = 0, DP[n+1,k] = bk*bk+1 +...+ bn-1*bn, DP[k,n+1] = ak*ak+1 +...+ an-1*an.

DP[n,k] = max{an*bk + bk+1*bk+2 +..+ bn-1*bn, DP[n,k+2] + bk*bk+1}

DP[k,n] = max{ak*bn + ak+1*ak+2 +..+ an-1*an, DP[k+2,n] + ak*ak+1}

DP[i,j] = max{DP[i+2,j] + ai*ai+1, DP[i,j+2] + bi*bi+1, DP[i+1,j+1] + ai*bi}.

And you return DP[1,1].

Explanation:
In each step you have to consider 3 options: take first 2 elements from remaining A, take first 2 element from remaining B, or take both from A and B (Since you can't change the order of A and B, you will have to take the first from A and first from B).

Comment: I can't see how your algorithm does not take into account twice or more the same element of one set.

Comment: Look here -  DP[i+1,j+1] + ai*bi, one from A and one from B

Comment: Sorry, it's not what I mean. How do you ensure in your algorithm that you don't have taken one element of A or B twice in different terms of the sum? I can't figure it out.

Comment: If I decide to take an element, I increase the index - so I can't take the same element again. For example, if I choose to take the 2 elements from A and don't use B this step, DP[i+2,j] will return. So we don't have the possibility to take ai or a+1 again.

Comment: Ok it convinces me :). +1 for this pretty solution by the way!

Comment: Looks nice, but `bk*bk+1` is confusing because it looks like you're adding 1 to `bk*bk`.  I suggest writing `b[k]*b[k+1]`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is rather simple. I just explore all the possible stable merges. Following the working C++ program:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

void find_max_sum(int *arr1, int len1, int *arr2, int len2, int sum, int& max_sum){
  if(len1 >= 2)
    find_max_sum(arr1+2, len1-2, arr2, len2, sum+(arr1[0]*arr1[1]), max_sum);
  if(len1 >= 1 && len2 >= 1)
    find_max_sum(arr1+1, len1-1, arr2+1, len2-1, sum+(arr1[0]*arr2[0]), max_sum);
  if(len2 >= 2)
    find_max_sum(arr1, len1, arr2+2, len2-2, sum+(arr2[0]*arr2[1]), max_sum);
  if(len1 == 0 && len2 == 0 && sum > max_sum)
    max_sum = sum;
}

int main(){
  int arr1[3] = {2,1,3};
  int arr2[3] = {3,7,9};
  int max_sum=0;
  find_max_sum(arr1, 3, arr2, 3, 0, max_sum);
  cout<<max_sum<<endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Above solution is quite simple. You can visualize it by making a tree with children as {a1[0],a1[1]}, {a1[0],a2[0]} and {a2[0],a2[1]}. Now expand each node with possible children (max 3) depending on the elements left in the arrays.

Comment: this is of exponential complexity! won't even return for array size like 70 elements/

Answer (score 0):

Define `F(i, j)` as the maximal pairwise sum that can be achieved by stable merging `Ai...An` and `Bj...Bn`.

At each step in the merge, we can choose one of three options:

1. Take the first two remaining elements of `A`.
2. Take the first remaining element of `A` and the first remaining element of `B`.
3. Take the first two remaining elements of `B`.

Thus, `F(i, j)` can be defined recursively as:

```
F(n, n) = 0
F(i, j) = max
(
    AiAi+1 + F(i+2, j), //Option 1
    AiBj + F(i+1, j+1), //Option 2
    BjBj+1 + F(i, j+2)  //Option 3
)
```

To find the optimal merging of the two lists, we need to find `F(0, 0)`, naively, this would involve computing intermediate values many times, but by caching each `F(i, j)` as it is found, the complexity is reduced to `O(n^2)`.

Here is some quick and dirty c++ that does this:

```
#include <iostream>

#define INVALID -1

int max(int p, int q, int r)
{
    return p >= q && p >= r ? p : q >= r ? q : r;
}

int F(int i, int j, int * a, int * b, int len, int * cache)
{
    if (cache[i * (len + 1) + j] != INVALID)    
        return cache[i * (len + 1) + j];

    int p = 0, q = 0, r = 0;

    if (i < len && j < len)
        p = a[i] * b[j] + F(i + 1, j + 1, a, b, len, cache);

    if (i + 1 < len)
        q = a[i] * a[i + 1] + F(i + 2, j, a, b, len, cache);

    if (j + 1 < len)
        r = b[j] * b[j + 1] + F(i, j + 2, a, b, len, cache);

    return cache[i * (len + 1) + j] = max(p, q, r);
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    int a[] = {2, 1, 3};
    int b[] = {3, 7, 9};
    int len = 3;

    int cache[(len + 1) * (len + 1)];
    for (int i = 0; i < (len + 1) * (len + 1); i++)
        cache[i] = INVALID;

    cache[(len + 1) * (len + 1)  - 1] = 0;

    std::cout << F(0, 0, a, b, len, cache) << std::endl;
}
```

If you need the actual merged sequence rather than just the sum, you will also have to cache which of `p, q, r` was selected and backtrack.

Comment: Check my solution. Will give an answer in O(n) time. I didn't find any contradicting test case

http://stackoverflow.com/a/11709668/808203

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve it by dynamic programming is to always store:

S[ i ][ j ][ l ] = "Best way to merge A[1,...,i] and B[1,...,j] such that, if l == 0, the last element is A[i], and if l == 1, the last element is B[j]".

Then, the DP would be (pseudo-code, insert any number at A[0] and B[0], and let the actual input be in A[1]...A[n], B[1]...B[n]):

```
S[0][0][0] = S[0][0][1] = S[1][0][0] = S[0][1][1] = 0; // If there is only 0 or 1 element at the merged vector, the answer is 0
S[1][0][1] = S[0][1][1] = -infinity; // These two cases are impossible
for i = 1...n:
    for j = 1...n:
        // Note that the cases involving A[0] or B[0] are correctly handled by "-infinity"
        // First consider the case when the last element is A[i]
        S[i][j][0] = max(S[i-1][j][0] + A[i-1]*A[i], // The second to last is A[i-1].
                         S[i-1][j][1] + B[j]*A[i]); // The second to last is B[j]
        // Similarly consider when the last element is B[j]
        S[i][j][1] = max(S[i][j-1][0] + A[i]*B[j], // The second to last is A[i]
                         S[i][j-1][1] + B[j-1]*B[j]); // The second to last is B[j-1]
 // The answer is the best way to merge all elements of A and B, leaving either A[n] or B[n] at the end.
return max(S[n][n][0], S[n][n][1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Merge it and sort it. May be merge sort. Sorted array give max value.(Merge is just append the arrays). complexity is nlogn.

Comment: Although I don't doubt that a sorted array *does* maximize the sum of products, the OP needs it such that the order of elements in the original array is preserved. So, using the example, `{1, 2, 3, 3, 7, 9}` is not acceptable because the 2 needs to remain in front of the 1.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution in Clojure, if you're interested in something a little more off the beaten path. It's O(n<sup>3</sup>), as it just generates all n<sup>2</sup> stable merges and spends n time summing the products. There's a lot less messing with offsets and arithmetic than the array-based imperative solutions I've seen, which hopefully makes the algorithm stand out more. And it's pretty flexible, too: if you want to, for example, include c2*c3 as well as c1*c2 and c3*c4, you can simply replace `(partition 2 coll)` with `(partition 2 1 coll)`.

```
;; return a list of all possible ways to stably merge the two input collections
(defn stable-merges [xs ys]
  (lazy-seq
   (cond (empty? xs) [ys]
         (empty? ys) [xs]
         :else (concat (let [[x & xs] xs]
                         (for [merge (stable-merges xs ys)]
                           (cons x merge)))
                       (let [[y & ys] ys]
                         (for [merge (stable-merges xs ys)]
                           (cons y merge)))))))

;; split up into chunks of two, multiply, and add the results
(defn sum-of-products [coll]
  (apply + (for [[a b] (partition 2 coll)]
             (* a b))))

;; try all the merges, find the one with the biggest sum
(defn best-merge [xs ys]
  (apply max-key sum-of-products (stable-merges xs ys)))

user> (best-merge [2 1 5] [3 7 9])
(2 1 3 5 7 9)
```

Comment: how is re-computation of sub problem prevented here?

Comment: It's not. I just put together something that's better than the "exponential complexity" the OP was claiming he had. TBH it's hard to imagine being any slower than n^3, since that's how fast a brute-force solution is.

Answer (score -2):

I think it would be better if you provide few more test cases. But I think the normal merging of two arrays similar to merging done in merge sort will solve the problem.

The pseudocode for merging arrays is given on [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Top-down_implementation).

> Basically it is the normal `merging algorithm  used in Merge Sort`. In
>   Merge sort the, arrays are sorted but here we are applying same merging
>   algorithm for unsorted arrays.

`Step 0`: Let `i` be the index for `first array(A)` and `j` be the `index for second     array(B`). `i=0 , j=0`

`Step 1`: `Compare A[i]=2 & B[j]=3`. Since `2<3` it will be the first element of the new `merged array(C)`. `i=1, j=0` (Add that number to the new array which is lesser)

`Step 2`: Again `Compare A[i]=1 and B[j]=3. 1<3` therefore `insert 1 in C. i++, j=0;`

`Step 3`: Again `Compare A[i]=3 and B[j]=3`. `Any number can go in C(both are same). i++, j=0;` (Basically we are increasing the index of that array from which number is inserted)

`Step 4`: Since the `array A is complete` just directly `insert the elements of Array B in C`. Otherwise repeat previous steps.

```
Array C = { 2, 1, 3, 3, 7,9}
```

I haven't done much research on it. So if there is any test case which could fail, please provide one.

Comment: Why only merge sort? If the ordering doesn't make sense in terms of *stable* merging then any algorithm solves the issue. See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11709421/538514

Comment: I havent said I am using merge sort. Am not doing any sorting. Just using the merging alogrithm used in merge sort. Your solution is wrong because we have to do stable merging(en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability

Comment: @Android Perhaps I misunderstood, but I think applying this algorithm to `{2, 1, 9}, {7, 3, 3}` yields `{2, 1, 7, 3, 3, 9}` when the optimal solution is `{2, 1, 9, 7, 3, 3}`

Comment: try [10, 0, 100] and [1,2,3], with your technique you would get [1, 2, 3, 10, 0, 100], so the answer would be 1*2+2*3+3*10+10*0+0*100, but we should have a solution > 100*3 = 300